# Digital Signature Verification Of Sender At Receiver Side

Tags: java, encryption, digital-signature, mtom, java-security

I want to send some of my files to client location and receive these file at client location. I am doing below given steps for sending and receiving,

For Sending

1. Compress the data file that needs to be transmitted using `java.util.zip.Deflater` JAVA API.
2. Encrypt the compressed file using Symmetric key.
3. Symmetric key is a combination of a randomly generated salt, password & secret key.
4. The symmetric key is than encrypted using the public key of the receiver. This key is than written to a file as a JSON string.
5. The encrypted data file & the key file is than zipped together.
6. The zip file is then signed using private key of sender and sent over using MTOM.

At Receiver End

1. The received zip file signature is verified using public key of sender
2. The zip file is than unzipped to retrieve - encrypted data file & key file.
3. The symmetric key is than decrypted using the private key of the receiver.
4. This Symmetric key is then used to decrypt the data file.
5. The decrypted compressed data file is than inflated to retrieve the original file.

I am able to do all the sender side operations.
At receiver side, I am able to do everything *except* signature verification of sender using public key. At receiver end, I have below given code -

```
public static void receive(String filePath, byte[] checksum)
            throws Exception {

        // Check if Sender Signature is Valid or not
        // Sender Public Key to Verify Signature.
        PublicKey senderPublicKey = CertificateUtil.readPublicKey("G:\\Work\\SMC\\temp\\Certs\\Sender\\publicKey.cer");
        byte[] dataBytes = FileUtils.getFileAsBytes(filePath);
        boolean verifySig = CertificateUtil.verifySig(dataBytes, senderPublicKey, checksum);
        System.out.println("Certificate Valid " + verifySig);

        // Unzip the file

        FileZipUtils.unZipFile(filePath, "G://Work//SMC//temp//Data//Receiver");

        // Read Key File and Populate key Object
        String readLines = FileUtils
                .readFirstLine("G://Work//SMC//temp//Data//Receiver//OPC_SNAPSHOT_Data_Req77_Key.csv");
        ObjectMapper mapperReceiver = new ObjectMapper();
        SymmetricKey readValue = mapperReceiver.readValue(readLines,
                SymmetricKey.class);

        // Decrypt Symmetric Key using Private Key
        PrivateKey privateKey = CertificateUtil
                .readPrivateKey("G:\\Work\\SMC\\temp\\Certs\\Receiver\\privatekey.pkcs8");
        byte[] recovered_message = CertificateUtil.decrypt(privateKey,
                readValue.getPasswordBytes());
        readValue.setPassword(new String(recovered_message, "UTF8"));
        System.out.println(new String(recovered_message, "UTF8"));

        // Decrypting the file using symmetric key.
        EncryptionUtil
                .decrypt("G://Work//SMC//temp//Data//Receiver//OPC_SNAPSHOT_Data_Req77_Encrtypt.csv",readValue);

    }
```

My problem is that to call receive function, I need `byte[]` checksum but from where i will get this checksum at receiver side.

Comment: Have you tried calculating it yourself using the same message digest used while performing the signature (e.g. if SHA256WithRSA, then you build an instance like so :  `MessageDIgest.getInstance("SHA-256")` );

Comment: The sender must send the signature performed at point 6. Checksum is a bad name because you can reproduce it at receiver side without the private key of sender, So you must send file&signature